# Unable to use nginx and express

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

when I type http://localhost:80[not an api path in my express api] this codeblock works with nginx and in postman I can see forwarded by nginx and also in access.logs

```
server 
    {
          listen       80;
          server_name  localhost;
          location / {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            }
          location = /50x.html {
          root   html;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }
```

but when I type https://localhost:5050/mongo/api it shows my express response but nothing about nginx and nothing in acess logs

```
server
    {
    listen 443 ssl;
    http2 on;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate      D:/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  D:/cert.key;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        
        }

        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
```

I have implemented https using mkcert and used the certificate for both express and nginx so what should I do so that I can make nginx work with express

Comment: Your nginx listen on port 443, you pass that request to port 5050... Why do you expect your nginx logs something when you talk to the upstream server directly without involving nginx